# Help with my corn plant

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis

[image]I received this plant in the hopes of making it thrive but it’s not. I have a humidifier, mist it daily and keep the soil appropriate for winter. I recently removed the dead leaves bit at the bottom but now it’s looking like this! I don’t know what to do anymore-any suggestions please?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you please tell us how much sunlight it's getting, and what keeping the soil 'appropriate for winter' means?

Comment: Looks wet. Water much less and move to the window.